# How does my hero compare to an average guy of a small late classical village?

Tags: biology, science-fiction, humans, culture

**The story**

My hero is an average European city boy of the 21th century. Eighteen years old, doing a bit of sport, eating well, with a job that doesn't require much physical efforts. He would appears just as normal as you, or I, do. For the sake of the story, he will be white of color with blue eyes.

By a series of spectacular events, he winds up through time up to the years ~200 A.D. where he meets with a local village between Macedonia and Gaul in the Ancient Rome. It is a really small entity, composed mostly of farmers and perhaps few blacksmiths or carpenters, which is an average in the countryside... and naturally, the people of this village will react to the newcomer.

**The question (s)**

How do this guy appears to the local residents, **physically speaking**? Is he seen as a well-built male, a weak boy or a totally normal resident? Does he appears young and ugly, or old and wise? Will he be able to do the work of a farmer, or will he collapse on the first day?

*...and more importantly*

Does he have a chance to join the auxiliary troops of the roman legion?

*PS: This is not about his clothes. To avoid confusion, let's imagine he managed to find local clothes that won't make him look weird to the people.*

Comment: *Where* does he come from? *Where* does he go?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T edited to add the 'where'. For some reasons, I thought I had put them.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T thanks for the earworm >.<

Comment: @dot_Sp0T hopefully not looking for that cotton

Comment: 200 AD is some three hundred years before the beginning of the Middle Ages. And it's a *very bad time* to choose to appear in the Roman Empire -- the 3rd century crisis looms, and won't be over until 270 AD or so. You may want to consider moving him to the 2nd century. And why join the auxiliaries? He is in the Empire, he may join a legion as a regular, with the advantage the after completion of his term he will be a citizen and most likely receive some land. And in that time 18 year olds were not "boys", they were adults. "Boys" were 12 year old or younger. How good are his Greek and Latin?

Comment: @AlexP I choosed the period for the exact reason that this is a bad time. For the problem of language, I deliberately left it out because it has something to do with 'how' he ends up here. In short: he has no problem communicating with the people of this village. As for the auxiliaries, I thought I was clever in my research by thinking you could not join the legion if you were not a citizen. Turns out I was wrong and this was bypassed numerous times.

Comment: The year 200AD is **late Classical Antiquity**, not Medieval.

Comment: No rotten teeth, no weals, no red neck, not covered in shit... obviously he is a king.

Comment: "*a local village between **Macedonia** and **Gaul** in the Ancient Rome*" that spans everything from Brittany through the Italian Alps, down through the Balkans into northern Greece.  There are many climates in there.  Be more specific.

Comment: He would probably kill _everyone_ in a large radius around him with all the modern pathogens he carries that the people of old have no defense against.

Comment: considering he will not speak the language they will probably think he is some kind of barbarian or escaped slave, He may be constantly harassed by the locals, think black man in early southern US.

Comment: You may find this video on the diet of the average citizen in ancient rome (80AD) helpful, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofiwRzoYrdw

Comment: He would appear glaringly white, at least until he got a nice base going ;)

Comment: _"Will he be able to do the work of a farmer"_ Speaking as a former farmer -- he might be able to physically perform the labor but it would be plainly obvious that he had no experience. For example, he'd have no proficiency with any tools, his hands would be blistered and bloody by day two, and he'd likely be skittish around large animals.

Comment: As many have said, he should be finished or almost finished growing and a few inches taller than most men of the era.  So he might join the army and feel like a sort of a giant, taller than almost all the other soldiers he meets.  Until he happens to meet the future emperor Gaius Julius Verus Maximinus and feels like a dwarf!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximinus_Thrax

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. As [This Q/A](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/17072/average-height-of-ancient-roman-men-and-women) suggests, he would probably be one of the taller ones, with the average male being under 1.70 meters.
2. He would probably have some problems with his body adjusting to much more endurance based tasks. For example I work in an office job and do regular workouts. Does not prepare me for going into the forest and making my own firewood -     muscle soreness is guaranteed every year.
3. He would have to adjust to a completely different diet. Probably have some problems with his digestive system. Compare this to a European boy going to the third world of today.

Given that he would probably be perceived as sickly during his struggles to adjust for the first few months. His physique would change during that time, possibly quite dramatic to leaner and more sinewy appearance.

He will have a hard time joining the auxiliary troops. I have first-hand experience in some medieval-style fighting and can tell you it is nothing we "modern" Europeans are used to. He will considerably lack the stamina to survive even the first five minutes. He needs at least half a year of mentoring and training to get to anywhere near the level he needs to be.

*My experience in that regard is: I used to run 10 km twice a week and had superior stamina to most of my peers, then. During my first fight - all out, only attacking an experienced sparring partner who would just defend - after 3 minutes I had to force myself to keep moving with all my will. After 5 minutes I was all but concentrated on breathing into my burning lungs and not collapsing.*

Comment: Also add for the fighting part that a change in climate will have a big affect - that 3 minutes goes to about 30 seconds on a hot July afternoon if you're wearing armour and gambeson.  Just something to remember if your hero gets moved.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook: Good point. Wearing Armor also has that effect - it just drains your energy-reserves a lot faster. I that example I wore about 10-15 kg (Chainmail, gambeson and helmet)

Comment: And once there it's better to continue the fight on your knees while begging for mercy - brings them in closer and you can get the groin shot in then which always gets a big laugh from the public.... going off topic now though. :)

Answer (score 24):

> How do this guy appears to the local residents, physically speaking?
>   Is he seen as a well-built male, a weak boy or a totally normal
>   resident?

He is probably 10 cm (~4 inches) taller than anybody else. His diet has been richer in protein than the people around him (who eat mostly cereals), and for that reason he has probably wider shoulders and chest than the average Ancient Roman. The few bits of armor from the era found show people being strong but quite lean (While rich people got fat).
One of the main problems is that probably his muscles are built for strength and not endurance. I mean: people were used to walk two or three hours if they had to go to a place, now, even some people think that walking more than 30 minutes is tiring. He will also discover he walks different than the people around him, using more the heel (being used to good shoes with cushion there) while people around him steps first with the sole and then with the heel. Also, he isn't used to harsh materials, so he doesn't have the necessary calluses.
Having blue eyes will probably make him quite attractive. Historical emperors were described with blue eyes for that reason.

> Does he appears young and ugly, or old and wise?

Probably younger (and dumb, he doesn't know anything). If he has taken a bit of care of himself, he won't have so many pimples and scars in the face. Romans offered their first beard when they were 16-17 years old and many people now doesn't get a beard at that age.

> Will he be able to do the work of a farmer, or will he collapse on the
>   first day?

I think he will be able to work for a while, although the heat/cold, the lack of protection from sun in the eyes and people only eating twice a day (with only one strong meal) will make his life more miserable.

> Does he have a chance to join the auxiliary troops of the roman
>   legion?

The new recruits had to pass an exam called *probatio*. It was more important for citizens, while the auxiliaries only cared if the recruit was trying to land a priviliged post, like being in administrative functions. However, the lack of ties to the community and knowledge of the local language will make a lot of people think he is a slave (slaves were usually carried far away from their origins and not taught Latin for that reason). Fugitive slaves sometimes joined the army, but will he avoid any people enslaving him during his time?

Comment: With this guy's lack of manual labor experience before he time travelled, he is bound to have soft hands and no calluses. I had friend who lived on a farm make such a comment about my town hands. That along with his lack of endurance mentioned by you and others, would seem to counter the argument that he could be mistaken for a runaway slave.... Unless he was mistaken for some sort a soft sex slave?

Comment: @EveryBitHelps Slaves in bath houses, personal shavers and artists (singers, musicians) would be "soft". Citarists, for example, must have looked like "pretty boys" because they had to be celibate, which means people lusted after them with intensity.

Answer (score 3):

The average Roman at the time was about 5'6", while the Gauls were 5'8" to 6'2". "Macedon to Gaul" was a very wide path of land inhabited by different people, and he would likely be taller than local people, but by no means too tall. His appearance (and probable accent) would suggest that he is likely a barbarian, and his healthy look might give an idea that he's hailing from barbarian nobility.

His physical fitness might be inadequate for day-to-day physical work, as well as the rigors of military life, but that can be improved, and his prospects as an auxiliary recruit should be bright. As far as a full legionnaire goes, he would have hard time convincing Romans that he's a full roman citizen and eligible to be a legionnaire.

Answer (score 0):

If the townspeople are imports from the Empire or the city of Rome, they are likely to be short, but the local people of Gaul were known to be especially tall, and physical fitness was culturally emphasized.  The people of the region became much shorter as the classical era gave way to the medieval era, but in 200 AD locals would have been quite tall, the population being smaller and the quality of the food being higher.

Comment: Tall for those times is still pretty short for today standards

Comment: So true. Also worth noting locales have their own standards of "tall & short". I grew up on the Channel Islands, just off Brittany, and we've older building and ancient statuary there from those times - and I can tell you they were *short* - like 5'-0"./